# vectorize groupby pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
day    time    category   count    

 1      1         a         13
 1      2         a         47
 1      3         a         1
 1      5         a         2
 1      6         a         4
 2      7         a         14
 2      2         a         10
 2      1         a         9
 2      4         a         2
 2      6         a         1
```

I want to group by day, and category and get a vector of the counts per time. Where time can be between 1 and 10. The max and min of time I have defined in two variables called max and min.

This is how I want the resulting dataframe to look:

```
day     category   count    

 1          a      [13,47,1,0,2,4,0,0,0,0]
 2          a      [9,10,0,2,0,1,14,0,0,0]
```

Does anyone know how to make this aggregation into a vaector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) for append missing categories and then `groupby` with `list`:

```
df = df.set_index(['day','time', 'category'])

a = df.index.levels[0]
b = range(1,11)
c = df.index.levels[2]

df = df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a,b,c], names=df.index.names), fill_value=0)
df = df.groupby(['day','category'])['count'].apply(list).reset_index()
print (df)
   day category                             count
0    1        a  [13, 47, 1, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1    2        a  [9, 10, 0, 2, 0, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0]
```

EDIT:

```
df = (df.set_index(['day','time', 'category'])['count']
       .unstack(1, fill_value=0)
       .reindex(columns=range(1,11), fill_value=0))
print (df)
time          1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
day category                                        
1   a         13  47   1   0   2   4   0   0   0   0
2   a          9  10   0   2   0   1  14   0   0   0

df = df.apply(list, 1).reset_index(name='count')
print (df)

   day                ...                                            count
0    1                ...                 [13, 47, 1, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1    2                ...                 [9, 10, 0, 2, 0, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0]

[2 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: This solution works! However, I have an issue with the Multidex using so much memory that I run out. Do you know any good way of fixing that?

Comment: @dagrun - Problem is with `MultiIndex` or with column `count` filled by `list`s? Because pandas working with lists, sets, dicts, tuples instead scalars like int, strings in values not so effective and if larger data there should be problem.

Comment: The memory problem happens on this line: "df = df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a,b,c], names=df.index.names), fill_value=0)"

Comment: @dagrun - proble is with `reindex`, in my opinion. Try test `mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a,b,c]` and then `df = df.reindex(mux, names=df.index.names), fill_value=0)`

Comment: I did.. My code never get to the reindex-step it runs out of memory on "mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a,b,c], names=df.index.names)"

Comment: Not sure if it help, what about `unstack` ? But if working with large data, better is add `RAM` or use some another librarly likle `dask`, `blaze`.

Comment: @dagrun - then there is multiple columns, simply remove it.

Comment: Unstack helped. Thank you! :D